# How to correct the nclines in this psmatrix flowchart?

Tags: pst-node, psmatrix

I was tryin and trying , and I have no solution.

I program many nclines but only appears 2
[image]

Why don´t show nclines from line 166?
Only shows 2 lines.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{setspace} % para que no afecte el interlineado a las notas de pié de página
%\usepackage{blindtext}  % para usar un texto-tipo de ejmplo Lore.... sin teclear a boleo, con \blindtext
\setstretch{1.5}
\usepackage{lipsum,mwe}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,latexsym}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand*{\upstrut}[1]{\rule{0pt}{#1}}% creates an invisible rule of height #1
\newcommand*{\negstrut}[1]{\rule[-#1]{0pt}{#1}}% creates an invisible rule of deptht #1
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{subfigure}   % para gráficos y ubicar cosas
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}  % otra opcion sería \usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathpazo}       % Fuente MathPazo
\usepackage{datetime}       % paquete para configurar formato de fecha y hora
\settimeformat{ampmtime}
\renewcommand*{\noon}{\pmname}
%\usepackage[ruled,vlined,lined,linesnumbered,algochapter,portugues]{algorithm2e} %Para presentar algoritmos
%\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}

%\usepackage{wrapfig} % para poner imagenes rodeadas de texto
%\usepackage[rflt]{floatflt}

\spanishdecimal{.}
    \usepackage[absolute]{textpos}


% ----------------------  PSTRICKS ---------------
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-3dplot,pst-node,pst-tree,pst-grad,pst-coil,pst-text,pst-3d,pst-eps,pst-fill,pstricks-add,multido}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-blur}

\newpsobject{cnodeblue}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue} %del diagrama tabu
\newpsobject{cnodepink}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink} %del diagrama tabu
\newpsobject{cnodegreen}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green} %del diagrama tabu
\newpsobject{psframegray}{psframe}{fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,shadow,blur} %del diagrama tabu
% ---- Fin Paquetes de pst-all


% ------------- CABECERAS y PIES DE PÁGINA ---------------------------
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % activamos el paquete para usar cabeceras y piés de página.
\cfoot{}
\newcommand{\sep}{\vspace{0.34cm}}
\newcommand{\redu}{\vspace{-0.56cm}}
\newcommand{\ul}{\underline}
% INSERTAR ESTAS DOS LINEAS SI NO FUNCIONA EL DIAGRAMA
%\newcommand*{\upstrut}[1]{\rule{0pt}{#1}}% creates an invisible rule of height #1   del diagrama tabu
%\newcommand*{\negstrut}[1]{\rule[-#1]{0pt}{#1}}% creates an invisible rule of deptht #1 del diagrama tabu
\newpsobject{cnodeblue}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue} %del diagrama tabu
\newpsobject{cnodepink}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink} %del diagrama tabu
\newpsobject{cnodegreen}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green} %del diagrama tabu
\newpsobject{psframegray}{psframe}{fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,shadow,blur} %del diagrama tabu

\DeclareMathOperator*{\minimizar}{Minimizar}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\maximizar}{Maximizar}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\optimizar}{Optimizar}


\definecolor{miorange}{RGB}{234, 112, 2}

\input{pssettings.tex}

\begin{document}

\resizebox{12cm}{!}{    % if you want to resize
\psset{framearc=0.2, shadowcolor=black!70, shadowangle=-90, unit=1.0cm}
\def\pscolhookii{\hskip 2cm}
\def\pscolhookiii{\hskip 2cm}
%\def\pscolhookiii{\psset[pst-node]{mcol = l}}

\begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.8, colsep=0.8]% defines the distance between two frames
    &[mnode = r, name = sa]
    \psframebox[shadow=true, framearc = 0.25,framesep=0.3]{$S_a=S_{inicial}$}
    \\[0.25cm]
%
    &[mnode = r, name = icero]
    \psframebox[shadow=true, framearc = 0.25,framesep=0.3]{$i=0$}
    \\[0.25cm]
%
    &[mnode = r, name = Tini]
    \psframebox[shadow=true, framearc = 0.25,framesep=0.3]{$T_0=r_0 \cdot f(S_a)$}\footnote{Esta elección podría tomarse como una Temperatura Fijada, y no dependiente de $S_{inicial}$}
    \\[0.25cm]
%
%  & [name = SA]
%  \psframegray(-1.00,-1.00)(1.00,1.00)
%    \cnodeblue(0,0){0.15}{Current}
%    \rput[t](0,-1.25){Solución Actual}&
%    \\[0.58cm] %era 1.25
%
[mnode = none, shadow=true, linearc = 0.05,framesep=0.3,name = Tnueva]
    \psframebox[shadow=true, framearc = 0.25,framesep=0.3]{$T_i = r_i \cdot T_{i-1}$}
&
 [mnode = none, shadow=true, linearc = 0.05,framesep=0.3,name = Tmax]
    \psdiabox[shadow=true, framearc = 0.25,framesep=0.15]{$T_i > T_{final}$\footnote{Alternativamente podría verificarse si $i>i_{max}$}}
     &
     [mnode = r, name = EMSV]
    \psframebox[shadow=true, framearc = 0.15]{\begin{tabular}{c@{\hskip\itemsep}l}
    \textbullet & Eligir Mejor\\ &Solución Visitada \end{tabular}}
    %%%%%%%%%%\\\textbullet & \textbf{Finalizar}
    \\[0.24cm]
%
[mnode = none, shadow=true, linearc = 0.05,framesep=-0.25,name =imasuno]
    \psframebox[shadow=true, framearc = 0.25,framesep=0.3]{$i = i + 1$}
&
 [mnode = none, shadow=true, linearc = 0.05,framesep=-0.25,name =jcero]
    \psframebox[shadow=true, framearc = 0.25,framesep=0.3]{$j = 0$}
    &
    [mnode = none, shadow=true, linearc = 0.05,framesep=-0.25,name =FIN]
    \psovalbox[shadow=true, framearc = 0.25,framesep=0.3]{FINALIZAR}
    \\[0.24cm]
%
&[mnode = none, shadow=true, linearc = 0.05,framesep=-0.25,name =jmax]
    \psdiabox[shadow=true, framearc = 0.25,framesep=0.3]{$j \leq m 0$}
    &
    \\[0.24cm]
%
&[mnode = none, shadow=true, linearc = 0.05,framesep=-0.25,name =GeneraN]
    \psframebox[shadow=true, framearc = 0.25,framesep=0.3]{Generar $N(S_a)$}
    &
    \\[0.24cm]
%
&[mnode = none, shadow=true, linearc = 0.05,framesep=-0.25,name =EV]
    \psframebox[shadow=true, framearc = 0.25,framesep=0.3]{Elegir $S_n \in N(S_a)$}
    &
    \\[0.24cm]
%
&[mnode = none, shadow=true, linearc = 0.05,framesep=-0.25,name =Deltaf]
    \psframebox[shadow=true, framearc = 0.25,framesep=0.3]{$\Delta f = f(S_n)-f(S_a)$}
    &
    \\[0.24cm]
%
&[mnode = none, shadow=true, linearc = 0.05,framesep=-0.48,name =DeltaMayorCero]
    \psdiabox[shadow=true, framearc = 0.25,framesep=-0.62]{\begin{tabular}{c}$\Delta f \geq 0$ \\ ó\\$\displaystyle \chi_{[0,1]} < e^{\frac{-\vert \Delta f \vert}{T_i}}$\\~ \end{tabular}}
    &
    [mnode = none, shadow=true, linearc = 0.05,framesep=-0.25,name =jmasuno]
    \psframebox[shadow=true, framearc = 0.25,framesep=0.3]{$j=j+1$}
    \\[0.24cm]
%
&[mnode = none, shadow=true, linearc = 0.05,framesep=-0.25,name =snsa]
    \psframebox[shadow=true, framearc = 0.25,framesep=0.3]{$S_n = S_a$}
    &
%
%%
\end{psmatrix}
%%% Links
\psset{linewidth=3pt, linecolor=red, arrows=->, nodesep=4pt,  linearc=0.25, angleB=180, shortput=nab, npos = 0.4}
%\ncline{LT}{CA}_{Si}
{\psset{nodesepB = 0.16, nodesepA=0.18}%
 \ncline[nodesepA = 0.18cm,nodesepB=0.1cm]{sa}{icero}%
 \ncline[nodesepA = 0.18cm,nodesepB=0.1cm]{icero}{Tini}%
 \ncline[nodesepA = 0.18cm,nodesepB=0.1cm]{Tini}{Tmax}%
 \ncline[nodesepA = 0.18cm,nodesepB=0.1cm]{Tmax}{EMSV}_{No}%   % HEREEEEE IS THE PROBLEMMMMMMMMMMM
 %%\ncline[nodesepA = 0.18cm,nodesepB=0.1cm]{icero}{sa}%
 \ncline[nodesepA = 0.18cm,nodesepB=0.1cm]{Tmax}{jcero}_{Si}%
 \ncline[nodesepA = 0.18cm,nodesepB=0.1cm]{jcero}{jmax}%
 \ncline[nodesepA = 0.18cm,nodesepB=0.1cm]{jmax}{GeneraN}%
 \ncline[nodesepA = 0.18cm,nodesepB=0.1cm]{GeneraN}{EV}%
 \ncline[nodesepA = 0.18cm,nodesepB=0.1cm]{EV}{Deltaf}%
 \ncline[nodesepA = 0.18cm,nodesepB=0.1cm]{Deltaf}{DeltaMayorCero}%
 }%
}
%\footnotetext{Alternativamente puede usarse otra}
\footnotetext{Esta elección podría tomarse como una Temperatura Fijada, y no dependiente de $S_{inicial}$}
\footnotetext{Alternativamente podría verificarse si $i>i_{max}$}

\end{document}
```

Comment: is your code snippet minimal? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason was that you had set `mnode=none`; you can't connect nodes that don't exist! For the footnotes problem, the usual `\footnotemark … \footnotetext` doesn't really work: the footnotes share the same (last) number. A solution consists in putting the psmatrix in a tabular and using the `threeparttable` package; this makes the footnotes appear at the bottom of the psmatrix, not at the bottom of the page — in my opinion, it's better so anyway. Finally I simplified the code, and commented out package loading that was not useful for the flowchart.

Btw, `subfigure` is an obsolete package, that should be replaced with one of `subfig`, `subcaption` or  `floatrow`. Also, if you use `mathpazo`, you shouldn't load `amssymb`, `amsfonts` or  `latexsymb: you'll have conflicts. Same problem loading`xcolor`with options and`pstricks`, as pstricks already loads xcolor`without` options. The solution consists in not loading xcolor and passing the xcolor option as an option for the documentclass. It will pass the option to pstricks, which will pass it to xcolor.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, x11names]{article}
\usepackage{setspace} % para que no afecte el interlineado a las notas de pié de página
%\usepackage{blindtext}  % para usar un texto-tipo de ejmplo Lore. ... sin teclear a boleo, con \blindtext
\setstretch{1.5}
%\usepackage{lipsum,mwe}
%\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}%,amsfonts,amssymb,latexsym
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand*{\upstrut}[1]{\rule{0pt}{#1}}% creates an invisible rule of height #1
\newcommand*{\negstrut}[1]{\rule[-#1]{0pt}{#1}}% creates an invisible rule of deptht #1
%\usepackage{subfigure}   % para gráficos y ubicar cosas
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue}

\usepackage{mathpazo}       % Fuente MathPazo
%\usepackage{datetime}       % paquete para configurar formato de fecha y hora
%\settimeformat{ampmtime}
%\renewcommand*{\noon}{\pmname}
%\usepackage[ruled,vlined,lined,linesnumbered,algochapter,portugues]{algorithm2e} %Para presentar algoritmos
%\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}

%\usepackage{wrapfig} % para poner imagenes rodeadas de texto
%\usepackage[rflt]{floatflt}

\spanishdecimal{.}
%    \usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

% ----------------------  PSTRICKS ---------------
\usepackage{pstricks}%[pdf]
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot,pst-tree,pst-grad,pst-coil,pst-text,pst-eps,pst-fill}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-blur}

\newpsobject{cnodeblue}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue} %del diagrama tabu
\newpsobject{cnodepink}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink} %del diagrama tabu
\newpsobject{cnodegreen}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green} %del diagrama tabu
\newpsobject{psframegray}{psframe}{fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,shadow,blur} %del diagrama tabu
% ---- Fin Paquetes de pst-all

% ------------- CABECERAS y PIES DE PÁGINA ---------------------------
%\usepackage{fancyhdr} % activamos el paquete para usar cabeceras y piés de página.
%\cfoot{}
\newcommand{\sep}{\vspace{0.34cm}}
\newcommand{\redu}{\vspace{-0.56cm}}
\newcommand{\ul}{\underline}
% INSERTAR ESTAS DOS LINEAS SI NO FUNCIONA EL DIAGRAMA
%\newcommand*{\upstrut}[1]{\rule{0pt}{#1}}% creates an invisible rule of height #1   del diagrama tabu
%\newcommand*{\negstrut}[1]{\rule[-#1]{0pt}{#1}}% creates an invisible rule of deptht #1 del diagrama tabu
\newpsobject{cnodeblue}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue} %del diagrama tabu
\newpsobject{cnodepink}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink} %del diagrama tabu
\newpsobject{cnodegreen}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green} %del diagrama tabu
\newpsobject{psframegray}{psframe}{fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,shadow,blur} %del diagrama tabu

\DeclareMathOperator*{\minimizar}{Minimizar}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\maximizar}{Maximizar}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\optimizar}{Optimizar}


\definecolor{miorange}{RGB}{234, 112, 2}

%\input{pssettings.tex}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}

\begin{document}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{p{\linewidth}}
\resizebox{12cm}{!}{    % if you want to resize
\psset{linearc = 0.05, framearc=0.25, shadow = true, framesep = 0.3, shadowcolor=black!70, shadowangle=-90, unit=1.0cm}
\def\pscolhookii{\hskip1.564cm}
\def\pscolhookiii{\hskip1.564cm}
%\def\pscolhookiii{\psset[pst-node]{mcol = l}}

\begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=1.4, colsep=0.8,mnode = r]% defines the distance between two frames
    &[name = sa]
    \psframebox{$S_a=S_\text{inicial}$}
    \\
%%
    &[name = icero]
    \psframebox{$i=0$}
    \\
%%
    & [name = Tini]
    \psframebox{$T_0=r_0  · f(S_a)$\,\tnote{1}
    }%
    \\
%%
%  & [name = SA]
%  \psframegray(-1.00,-1.00)(1.00,1.00)
%    \cnodeblue(0,0){0.15}{Current}
%    \rput[t](0,-1.25){Solución Actual}&
%    \\[0.58cm] %era 1.25
%
[name = Tnueva]
    \psframebox{$T_i = r_i  · T_{i-1}$}
& [name = Tmax]
    \psdiabox[framesep=0pt]{\raisebox{0pt}[0.5cm][0.3cm]{$T_i > T_\text{final}$\,\tnote{2}}
    }
     &   [name = EMSV]
    \psframebox[framearc = 0.15]{\begin{tabular}{c@{\hskip\itemsep}l}
    \textbullet & Eligir Mejor\\ &Solución Visitada \end{tabular}}
    %%%%%%%%%%\\\textbullet & \textbf{Finalizar}
    \\
%%
[name =imasuno]
    \psframebox{$i = i + 1$}
&  [name =jcero]
    \psframebox{$j = 0$}
&  [name =FIN]
    \psovalbox{FINALIZAR}
    \\
%%
& [name =jmax]
    \psdiabox{$j \leq m_0$}
    &
    \\
%%
& [name =GeneraN]
    \psframebox{Generar $N(S_a)$}
    &
    \\
%%
& [name =EV]
    \psframebox{Elegir $S_n  ∈ N(S_a)$}
    &
    \\
%%
& [name =Deltaf]
    \psframebox{$Δ f = f(S_n)-f(S_a)$}
    &
    \\
%%
& [name =DeltaMayorCero]%
    \psdiabox[framesep = 0pt]{\raisebox{0pt}[0.6cm][0.8cm]{\makebox[2.8cm]{$ \begin{array}{c}Δ f \geq 0\\[-4pt] \text{ ó} \\[-4pt] 
     χ_{[0,1]} < \smash[t]{e^{-\frac{\vert Δ f \vert}{T_i}}}\end{array} $}}}
    & [framesep=-0.25,name =jmasuno]
    \psframebox{$j=j+1$}
    \\
%%
& [framesep=-0.25,name =snsa]
    \psframebox{$S_n = S_a$}
    &
%%
\end{psmatrix}
%% Links
\psset{linewidth=3pt, linecolor=red, shadow = false, arrows=->, nodesep=4pt,  linearc=0.25, angleB=180, shortput=nab}%
%\ncline{LT}{CA}_{Si}
{\psset{nodesepB = 0.16, nodesepA=0.18}%
 \ncline{sa}{icero}%
 \ncline{icero}{Tini}%
 \ncline{Tini}{Tmax}%[nodesepA = 0.18cm,nodesepB=0.1cm]
 \ncline{Tmax}{jcero}_{Si}%
 \ncline{jcero}{jmax}%
 \ncline{jmax}{GeneraN}_{Si}%
 \ncline{GeneraN}{EV}%
 \ncline{EV}{Deltaf}%
 \ncline{Deltaf}{DeltaMayorCero}%
 \ncline{DeltaMayorCero}{snsa}_{Si}
 \ncline{DeltaMayorCero}{jmasuno}^{No}
 \ncangle[angleB = -90]{snsa}{jmasuno}
 \ncangle[angleA = 90, angleB= 0]{jmasuno}{jmax}
 \ncangle[angleA = 180,angleB = -90]{jmax}{imasuno}\nbput[npos = 0.5]{No}%
 \ncline{imasuno}{Tnueva}
 \ncline{Tnueva}{Tmax}
 \ncline{Tmax}{EMSV}^{No}%
 }%
}
\bigskip
\end{tabular}
%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{tablenotes}\scriptsize
%\footnotetext{Alternativamente puede usarse otra}
\item[1]{Esta elección podría tomarse como una Temperatura Fijada, y no dependiente de $ S_\text{inicial} $}
\item[2]{Alternativamente podría verificarse si $i>i_\text{max}$}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU,... VERY MUCH!! for the solution and for the multiple comments that I´m taking in account to modify and correct in the future. I´m very gratefull to you, Bernard.

Comment: Yesterday I starting use subcaption (for other post) and I´m very happy with subcaption. Thank you for mathpazo notes, I don´t known all what you wrote, I only put packages, packages, and packages,... a big truck full of packages :-) that is not good because of the conflicts

Comment: The issue of xcolor options It´s a pity because I see a names and a table, but then a package needs a partiular option, other needs other options, and finally, I only use black,red,blue,green and gray. And I would like to select one to use always to use any tother color of the multiple tables of xcolor. What  do you recomend me in this sense.

Comment: At last.... Yesterday I was suggested to view the post of obsolote packages, I LIKED IT, It´s a must-seen package :-) The question is: Are there any other post that many of we should/must view to learn details, options,avoinding problems, good practices, suggestion to learn well ?

Comment: It´s a little frutrating LATEX, because I (after your answers) say "YES, NOW I KNOW DO THIS", but in a few hours/days I want to do a little little whing more, and :-( all changes, I need other package or change any structure, or appears a conflict.... LATEX is beautifull, but in this sense it´s a little frustrating.

Comment: All is so sensible. In your code, I tried to modify  def\pscolhookii{\hskip 2cm}
\def\pscolhookiii{\hskip 2cm} with only 1cm.... and the flowchart goes to the 2nd page. A little change, anything suposse a headache

Comment: playing with your question... http://sensa.square7.ch/playingwithbernardscodesn26.jpg

Comment: @Mika Ike: That's many questions;) — I'll try to answer gradually. About the `xcolor options`: it's a general rule that, if you load `any` package with different options, LaTeX delivers this message: `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package …`. Concerning `obsolete` packages, the reference is `l2tabu, v. 2.3`, originally in german and translated into English (v. 1.8), French, Italian and Spanish (older version).

Comment: @Mika Ike: decreasing \hskip in \pscolhookii & iii makes the flowchart go to a second page? That' quite strange. Added: I've just tested and found the limit was 1.564 cm! Really don't understand. I suppose it must be a problem with overlapping boxes.

Comment: @Mika Ike: As to your 3 colourful questions in the linked document, I don't know. I have no such behaviour. What you must understand is the notion of "under" and "above" is relative to the direction of the arrows: `ncline{A}{B}^{something}` is the same as `ncline{B}{A}_{something}`. I'll update at once my answer.

Comment: but.. Is so really strange  the pink question of the image.. Appears "No", don´t typping "No" in the code line (pink)

Comment: the problem of appears "No" without puttin in pink-code, is that \ncline{Tmax}{EMVS}_{No} was DUPLICATE